# how to convert pdf to image in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to make pdf to image converter in react native. I tried using some packages but they are not working.so is there any way to convert pdf to image?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve the PDF to thumbnail using the npm package called [react-native-pdf-thumbnail](https://github.com/songsterq/react-native-pdf-thumbnail)

Have a try with this npm package

Comment: @Raj, What actual issue you are facing ?

Comment: i have a pdf of certificate which i wnat to convert to png for users

Comment: @Raj,  It's Working fine over here, please have a try by cloning the above repo and running the example project inside the repo.

Comment: I tried the react-native-pdf-thumbnail's example, and it works fine but couldn't capture the annotations in pdf. Any other library which has support for annotation too.

Answer (score -1):

here you can pick pdf from the file manager

```
var results = await DocumentPicker.pickMultiple({
type: [DocumentPicker.types.pdf], });
```

`npm install react-native-pdf-thumbnail`

here you can convert pdf to image

```
const filePath = results[0].uri;
const data2 = await PdfThumbnail.generateAllPages(filePath, 90);

console.log(data2);
```